# Did angular2 change how their * syntax work with custom structural directives?

Tags: angular

I'm reading the developer guide on structural directives.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

The  example no longer seem to work. If I desugar it manually into

```
<template [myUnless]="condition">
  <p>
    condition is false, myUnless is false.
  </p>
</template>
```

it works fine. Otherwise I get an error **Can't bind to 'myUnless' since it isn't a known native property**

Comment: Could you edit your question with the whole component code ?

Comment: I think it's related to this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5894

Comment: yeah I think that's the issue I'm seeing.